# Reading rational numbers from a text file line by line and add numbers in each line with some lines having wrong input

Tags: java

I want to write Java code which reads rational numbers from a text file and add them line by line. The numbers are seperated by "and". However, the sum of the lines has the wrong input.

These are the contents of the text file:

```
1234/5678and8765/4321
0/1and34/675
apple/23and23/x
-346/74and54/32
-232/884and-33/222
1.2/31and-1/4
-5and1/2
0and3/4
2/3and0
-4/5and5
```

I have written some code but it terminates when it reaches wrong input. I feel it can be improved

```
import java.io.*;

class ReadAFile{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        try{

            File myFile = new File("input.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(myFile);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            String line = null;

            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){

                String [] value = line.split("and");

                String part1 = value[0];
                String part2 = value[1];

                String[] num = part1.split("/");
                String[] dig = part2.split("/");

                float x = Integer.parseInt(num[0]);
                float y = Integer.parseInt(num[1]);

                float a = x/y;

                float p = Integer.parseInt(dig[0]);
                float q = Integer.parseInt(dig[1]);

                float b = p/q;


                float sum = a + b;
                System.out.println(sum);


            }

            reader.close();
        }

        catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In the output, I expect the addition of every line that has correct input to be displayed while skipping lines with wrong input.

This is my output so far:

```
2.2457957
0.05037037
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "apple"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
        at ReadAFile.main(ReadAFile.java:26)
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

Comment: How do you want to handle the wrong input: ignore/reject, make protocol of it or fix it (apple => 4543). My be you need your own parser.

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt throws a NumberFormatException, so you will need try/catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can process these lines efficiently, both validating them and parsing them with a single regular expression.  No need for all the splits, which make a bunch of copies of things.  Here is such a solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    try {
        File myFile = new File("/tmp/input.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(myFile);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        // The expression for a single float
        String floatPat = "([-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+)";

        // Construct expression that models our input...two terms separated by 'and',
        // each of which is a float followed optionally by a slash and a second float.
        String fullPat = "@(/@)?and@(/@)?".replace("@",floatPat);
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(fullPat);

        String line = null;
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {

            // Skip empty lines
            if (line.isEmpty())
                continue;

            // apply our expression.  If it matches, process the line
            Matcher m = pat.matcher(line);
            if (m.matches()) {

                // Pull the first value of the first term out of the match
                float x = Float.parseFloat(m.group(1));

                // If the first term had a second part, pull out that float
                float y = (m.group(3) == null)? 1.0f : Float.parseFloat(m.group(3));

                float a = x / y;

                // Pull the first value of the second term out of the match
                float p = Float.parseFloat(m.group(4));

                // If the second term had a second part, pull out that float
                float q = (m.group(6) == null)? 1.0f : Float.parseFloat(m.group(6));

                float b = p / q;

                float sum = a + b;
                System.out.println(sum);
            }
            else {
                // Do something with  bad input
                System.out.println("Bad input: " + line);
            }
        }

        reader.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note that here, I choose to print the invalid lines too, noted as such.

Output:

```
2.2457957
0.05037037
Bad input: apple/23and23/x
-2.9881759
-0.4110921
-0.21129033
-4.5
0.75
0.6666667
4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **regex("[0-9/.-]+")** to validate whether part data has only rational numbers or not.You have to use Float.parseFloat() instead of parseInt(). parseInt will throw NumberFormatException for float numbers.

**For Example:** While parsing line-6 in your file (Integer.parseInt("1.2");) will throw NumberFormatException.

```java
package com.stackovflow.problems;

import java.io.*;

class ReadAFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            File myFile = new File("input.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(myFile);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            String line = null;
            String onlyFloatNumRegex = "-?[0-9.]+";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] value = line.split("and");
                if (value.length == 2) {
                    String part1 = value[0];
                    String part2 = value[1];
                    if (part1.matches("[0-9/.-]+") && part2.matches("[0-9/.-]+")) {

                        String[] num = part1.split("/");
                        String[] dig = part2.split("/");
                        if (num.length == 2 && dig.length == 2 && num[0].matches(onlyFloatNumRegex) && num[1].matches(onlyFloatNumRegex)
                                && dig[0].matches(onlyFloatNumRegex) && dig[1].matches(onlyFloatNumRegex)) {
                            float x = Float.parseFloat(num[0]);
                            float y = Float.parseFloat(num[1]);

                            float a = x / y;

                            float p = Float.parseFloat(dig[0]);
                            float q = Float.parseFloat(dig[1]);

                            float b = p / q;

                            float sum = a + b;
                            System.out.println(sum);

                        }

                    }
                }

            }

            reader.close();
        }

        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your preflight checks will catch everything in the OPs sample data, but will not catch all bad input.  For example, a '0-0' term in the input will still cause an exception because this is not a valid floating point number.

Comment: Thank you very much.Program now working. I had to add other if statements to cater for scenarios: num.length==1&&dig.length==2 and num.length==2&&dig.length==1

Comment: @Steve I have updated my answer to handle invalid floating numbers

Comment: ok, seems like that should work.  seems inefficient though with 6 regex matches per line of input in addition to the work to cut apart the input.  Why not write a single regex to test the whole input line with?